# Use common macros (eg. $OutDir) in Visual Studio 2022 as part of the Debug run Config

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

i'm pretty convinced that i've done that in older Versions of VS. But as sometimes mind tricks you, it could be possible that it is not possible at all:

I have a classLib (plugin) written in C# using **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 ((64-bit) - Current Version 17.2.6)**. The Output dir is changed into a dir, in which the original Program is located, having a plugin dir. To debug, i've changed the Start action:

- Start external programm
- Path to program
- working dir = path to outputdir

Using the browse feature always gives you an absolut path, you can change that to a relative path **( i know that and i'm doing it, this does not need to be an advice to me!)**. But sometimes, when changing something in config it overrides my relative path to an absolute again.

Is or was it possible to use something like  $(OutDir)\external.exe (with or without backslash)? Any ideas?

## no relevant informations below this point!

### Why does this bothers me in first place ?

We are Working in a team of 6 developers and are replacing our runsettings so often that i'm quite annoyed...
Not everyone of use has the same directory structure

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that paths like $(OutDir)\external.exe cannot be used in starting external programs.

You can try to add this in the .csproj file:

```
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>$(OutputPath)external.exe</StartProgram>
```

I did this:

[image]